# Cannot map inner navigation property using automapper. EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have such entities for that particular issue: `Album`, `Photo`. Each `Album` contains a **collection** of `Photo`s.

And Dto classes: `AlbumWithPhotosDto`, which contains a **collection** of `PhotoDto`.

In my automapper profile I described the mapping rules for all entities:

```
CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AverageRate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ratings.Average(r => r.Rate)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.RatesCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ratings.Count))
                .ReverseMap();

 CreateMap<Album, AlbumWithPhotosDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotosNum, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.Count))
                .ReverseMap();
```

Firstly I used `LazyLoadingProxies` and when I tried to map an `Album` to an `AlbumWithPhotosDto`.

I got exception:

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: Album -> AlbumWithPhotosDto DAL.Entities.Album ->
> BLL.DataTransferObjects.AlbumWithPhotosDto
>
> Type Map configuration: Album -> AlbumWithPhotosDto DAL.Entities.Album
> -> BLL.DataTransferObjects.AlbumWithPhotosDto
>
> Destination Member: Photos

Then I changed lazy loading on explicit loading such as:

```
_context.Albums
            .Include(a => a.Photos)
            .Include(a => a.Author)
```

But again I got the same exception. How I can fix this?

Here the additional definitions of classes:

```
 public class Album : IEntity<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Album name.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Album short description.
        /// </summary>
        public string Description { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Whether the other users can view and rate the album photos or not.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Foreign key, creator's id.
        /// </summary>
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// User who created the album but not obviously author of all photos.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Photos in album.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; } = new HashSet<Photo>();
    }
```

```
public class Photo : IEntity<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Optional photo short description.
        /// </summary>
        public string Description { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Path to the photo file on the hard drive.
        /// </summary>
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Date and time of uploading.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Photo ratings by users.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; } = new HashSet<Rating>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Foreigh key, author's id.
        /// </summary> 
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class AlbumWithPhotosDto : IDtoMetadata
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        public int PhotosNum { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PhotoDto> Photos { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class PhotoDto : IDtoMetadata
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Base64 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double AverageRate { get; set; }
        public int RatesCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RatingDto> Ratings { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The mapping for Rating is also present, I skipped this for brevity

Comment: Maybe context was disposed. Did you try adding a .ToArray() at the end of your query, before mapping?

Comment: Yes, I forced the query execution and the Album objects were successfully queried, the context works ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After step by step investment I realized that the problem nevertheless was in that line in mapping config:

```
CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AverageRate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ratings.Average(r => r.Rate)))
```

The solution was to take care about a default value in case of 0 ratings.

```
CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AverageRate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ratings.Select(r => r.Rate).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average()))
```

And now even the LazyLoadingProxies are successfully mapped which I considered incompatible with the automapper before.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the `Ratings` in your query. Therefore, AutoMapper is basically trying to call `.Average()` on an empty collection, and hence the failure.

Modify your query as -

```cs
var albums = _context.Albums
            .Include(a => a.Photos).ThenInclude(p => p.Ratings)
            .Include(a => a.Author)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I did it, nothing changed, I commented out the ratings collection in the dto class, all is the same.

Comment: @AlexandrBarylo Then please edit the post and share the complete mapping code, all the models, and also how you are calling the `.Map()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the exception message, the issue is with 'Photos' property in the 'AlbumWithPhotosDto'. Change the type to 'List', and try that way.